# PHP code to arrange records as per distance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, geolocation

I tried the following method which worked for my old database structure

```
$lat = '-27.560263394765027';
$long = '153.08231055736542'; 
 $query = "SELECT * , ((
    ACOS( SIN( ".$lat." * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( lat * PI( ) /180 ) + COS( ".$lat." * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( lat * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( (
     ".$long." - lon) * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( )) *60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `km_stores` HAVING `distance` <=100 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10";
```

And, I am trying to apply the same principle and find the nearest 30 stores within maximum 100km radius and this time my database structure is entirely different and I need to run set of sql queries to get the required output. My queries are

```
$select_resname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE  `form_name` =  'Add Store' AND  `field_name` =  'store-name' LIMIT 0 , 30");
$select_resdesc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE  `form_name` =  'Add Store' AND  `field_name` =  'store-description' LIMIT 0 , 30");
$select_reslat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE  `form_name` =  'Add Store' AND  `field_name` =  'store-latitude' LIMIT 0 , 30");
$select_reslong = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE  `form_name` =  'Add Store' AND  `field_name` =  'store-longitude' LIMIT 0 , 30");
while(($fetch_resname = mysql_fetch_array($select_resname)) && ($fetch_resdesc = mysql_fetch_array($select_resdesc)) && ($fetch_reslat = mysql_fetch_array($select_reslat)) && ($fetch_reslong = mysql_fetch_array($select_reslong))){
    // Print the output
}
```

In this case how can I arrange records as per GEO location?

Comment: ...and what is your database structure?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [`ORDER BY()`](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-ORDER-BY.asp) and/or [`GROUP BY()`](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-GROUP-BY.asp)

Comment: @Fred-ii- GROUP BY? I don't see that. !?!

Answer (score 1):

```
$select_resname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE  `form_name` =  'Add Store' AND  `field_name` =  'store-name' LIMIT 0 , 30");
$select_resdesc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE  `form_name` =  'Add Store' AND  `field_name` =  'store-description' LIMIT 0 , 30");
$select_reslat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE  `form_name` =  'Add Store' AND  `field_name` =  'store-latitude' LIMIT 0 , 30");
$select_reslong = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE  `form_name` =  'Add Store' AND  `field_name` =  'store-longitude' LIMIT 0 , 30");

$resultAreas          = array();
while(($fetch_resname = mysql_fetch_array($select_resname)) && ($fetch_resdesc = mysql_fetch_array($select_resdesc)) && ($fetch_reslat = mysql_fetch_array($select_reslat)) && ($fetch_reslong = mysql_fetch_array($select_reslong))){
    $areaResult1      = @$fetch_resname["area_field"];
    $areaResult2      = @$fetch_resdesc["area_field"];
    $areaResult3      = @$fetch_reslat["area_field"];
    $areaResult4      = @$fetch_reslong["area_field"];

    if($areaResult1!="")
    {
        $resultAreas[]= $areaResult1;
    }
    if($areaResult2!="")
    {
        $resultAreas[]= $areaResult2;
    }
    if($areaResult3!="")
    {
        $resultAreas[]= $areaResult3;
    }
    if($areaResult4!="")
    {
        $resultAreas[]= $areaResult4;
    }
}
sort($resultAreas);
print_r($resultAreas); // prints you the sorted result
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in real time as its just sorting as per numeric order but not as per distance. Also, getting output just as "Array". +1 for your code.